# How to incremented my number with a while?

Tags: javascript, react-native, while-loop

I have a decibel meter and my value are between 1 and 800. I did a code but i have to write like 100 lines to increase my number between 1 and 800 and it's not in details.  i think i can do a loop but i'm a beginner with JS and i struggle to find the good solution. Someone knows how to do this ?

Also my code :

```
if (value < 70 && value > -10) {
            this.setState({sound: 0});
            this.state.soundArray.push(0);
          } else if (value > 70 && value <= 72) {
            this.setState({sound: 10});
            this.state.soundArray.push(10);
          } else if (value > 72 && value <= 74) {
            this.setState({sound: 20});
            this.state.soundArray.push(20);
          } else if (value > 74 && value <= 76) {
            this.setState({sound: 30});
            this.state.soundArray.push(30);
          } else if (value > 76 && value <= 78) {
            this.setState({sound: 40});
            this.state.soundArray.push(40);
          } else if (value > 78 && value <= 80) {
            this.setState({sound: 50});
            this.state.soundArray.push(50);
          } else if (value > 80 && value <= 82) {
            this.setState({sound: 55});
            this.state.soundArray.push(55);
          } else if (value > 82 && value <= 84) {
            this.setState({sound: 60});
[...]
```

Comment: Forget coding for a moment - can you write a mathematical equation to calculate `sound` based on `value`?

Comment: value = x
sound=y
Note that the  max value for x is 800
y = 160/x

Comment: OK if that is the mathematical equation, then you don't need repeated `if...else if...else if...`. You can just calculate `sound` based on `value`, store it in some temporary variable, and then pass that variable to `setState` and add to `soundArray`. (You probably still need separate code to handle the exception scenarios like min/max values etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need some kind of value to sound converter? Like this:

```
function valueToSoundConverter(value) {
  if (value > - 10 && value <= 70) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.ceil((value - 70)/2)*10;
}
```

and then rewrite your code to

```
const sound = valueToSoundConverter(value);
this.setState({sound: sound});
this.state.soundArray.push(sound);
```

Comment: this is also my let value 
 let value = data.value + 160; (data.value is the sound catch on the decibel meter)